# Kendo Upload widget inside Kendo Grid not posting the selected file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-upload

I am new to Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC and I am facing a problem when I try to send and image with the HTTP request through a Kendo Upload control inside of a Kendo Grid.

Here is the code to my grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<RedeemViewModel>()
      .Name("RedeemGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(c => c.image).EditorTemplateName("image");
          columns.Bound(c => c.Title);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Description);
          columns.Bound(c => c.Points);
          columns.Command(command => command.Edit());
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar =>
      {
          toolbar.Create();
      })
      .Scrollable()
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .Model(model => model.Id(field => field.Key))
          .Read(read => read.Action("GetRedeems", "Redeem"))
          .Create(create => create.Action("AddRedeem", "Redeem"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateRedeem", "Redeem"))
      )
      )
```

I am using an EditorTemplate that I created that contains the Kendo Upload. Here it is:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
  .Name("image")
  .Multiple(false)
  )
```

And here is the RedeemViewModel in which I am trying to receive the posted image:

```
public class RedeemViewModel
{
    public Guid? Key { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase image { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code to my Action method the grid targets

```
public ActionResult AddRedeem([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, RedeemViewModel redeemViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // create a new redeem object
                Redeem redeem = new Redeem
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Description = redeemViewModel.Description,
                    Points = redeemViewModel.Points,
                    Title = redeemViewModel.Title
                };

                // try to save the image
                var imageSaved = StorageService.SaveImage(redeemViewModel.image, ImageCategory.Redeem, redeem.Id.ToString());

                // check if image was saved
                if (imageSaved)
                {
                    // update the redeem's image property
                    redeem.Image = redeem.Id + Path.GetExtension(redeemViewModel.image.FileName);
                }

                // persist the redeem object to the database
                redeem = RedeemService.Add(redeem);
                redeemViewModel.Key = redeem.Id;
            }
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

And here is the request that actually gets sent:

```
POST http://localhost:3705/Redeem/AddRedeem HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3705
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 64
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:3705
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36       (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:3705/Redeem/Index
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

sort=&group=&filter=&Key=&Title=test&Description=test&Points=200
```

When I debug the Action method, I find that the image property of the RedeemViewModel is always null.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using HttpPostedBaseFile?

Comment: I don't think there is such a class. I am using HttpPostedFileBase as you can see in the RedeemViewModel